# Multiple dynamic HTML parameters in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to assign an array of params and values to an html container like in this example:

```
let myParams = ['param1', 'param2', 'param2];
let myValues = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
<div :[myParams]="myValue"></div>
```

The ouptput should be:

`<div param1="val1" param2="val2" param3=val3"></div>`

Would be great if anyone of you knows a solution for this one.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be helpful: https://alligator.io/vuejs/passing-multiple-properties/

You can use `v-bind` to bind multiple parameters. To do that, you should merge your arrays into one object and then bind this object.

Something like that:

```
let data = {
  param1: 'val1',
  param2: 'val2',
  param3: 'val3'
}
<div v-bind="data"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is often a good idea to bind to a attributes object directly so that the template is cleaner

```
data(){
  return {
    multipleAttributes:[{param1:'val1'},{param2:'val2'},{param3:'val3'}]
  }
}
```

and bind to your div tag

```
<div v-bind="multipleAttributes"></div>
```

read docs here [muiltple values](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Multiple-Values)